# Access Windows File System From Linux OS

Tags: centos, filesystems, windows, crash

My sister's computer has stopped working.  I am not entirely sure what the problem is, but I think it is a Windows/software issue.  She really just wants to retrieve the pictures off it.  I am wondering if I could install a Linux OS (CentOS is the only one with which I am little familiar) on the free space and access her Windows file system.  I know there are several 'what ifs', but is this a possibility?

Comment: A safer alternative might be to use a live Linux distribution on a USB stick or some other removable media, then fetch the pictures to another removable media, e.g. external hard disk.

Comment: as SamiLaine said, I would certainly look at booting from a LiveCD or a USB disk before trying to install an OS on the disk's free space.

Comment: Have made a boot disk on SystemRescueCD.  I look forward to trying this out.  I hope it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes !

Better use a rescue distribution like [SystemRescueCD](http://www.sysresccd.org/Download).
It includes already all utilities you need including partition backup and windows File system support.

It's easy to use. and you can just run it from an [USB Flash Drive](http://www.sysresccd.org/Sysresccd-manual-en_How_to_install_SystemRescueCd_on_an_USB-stick#A.29_Recommended_USB_installation_method_from_Linux).

Answer (score 1):

First you'll have to make sure which hard disk and partition Windows is occupying, let's suppose it's on /dev/sda1.

Open a terminal, run

```
# mount -t ntfs /dev/sda1 /some/random/empty/directory/
```

Your Windows files should be accessible from the directory then.